# $\sigma$ -algebra and function defined in it.

Tags: real-analysis, probability-theory, measure-theory

Let $(X, \mathscr A, \mu)$ be $\sigma$ - algebra and let's define function $f:X\rightarrow Y$. Let's define a family of sets $$\mathscr B=\{B\subset Y:f^{-1}(B)\in\mathscr A\}$$and function $$\nu: \mathscr B\rightarrow\nu(B)=\mu(f^{-1}(B))\in[0,+\infty).$$
Check if $\mathscr B$ is also a $\sigma$-algebra on a set $Y$ and if $\nu$ is a measure.

I checked the first property, which is that an empty set is in $\mathscr B$. I managed to prove the second property as well, but only under the condition that $f$ is bijective, but I'm not really sure what about the third one.

Comment: In your question I only meet **two** things to be checked: that $\mathscr B$ is a $\sigma$-algebra and that $\nu$ is a measure on it. So I don't understand how you come to **three** properties. Do you mean the $3$ conditions for being a $\sigma$-algebra (non-empty, closed under complements, closed under countable unions)?

Comment: Yes, I meant the 3 conditions that are required for $\mathscr B$ to be a $\sigma$-algebra.

Comment: The preimage always preserves complements, intersections, and unions, unlike the direct image (which preserves unions, but not generally intersections or complements).

Comment: On base of definition of preimage it can be proved (and it is not difficult) that $f^{-1}(B^{\complement})=(f^{-1}(B))^{\complement}$ and $f^{-1}(\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}B_n)=\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty} f^{-1}(B_n)$. That opens the door to prove that $\mathscr B$ is indeed a $\sigma$-algebra. Bijectivitiy of $f$ is not necessary.

Comment: If you do not know the things Daniel and drhab said, then that is your problem.  Prove them for yourself from the definitions.